# Why is chrome and firefox ignoring this multiple selector CSS rule?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, cross-browser

For whatever reason, it looks like Chrome and Firefox are ignoring this CSS rule. I don't see them being applied in dev tools anywhere and am confused. I noticed that Safari is applying them, but Chrome and Firefox are not.

```css
#et-boc .et-l .hentry,
#et-boc .et-l a,
#et-boc .et-l a:active,
#et-boc .et-l blockquote,
#et-boc .et-l div:not(.woocommerce-message, .star-rating),
#et-boc .et-l em,
#et-boc .et-l form,
#et-boc .et-l h1,
#et-boc .et-l h2,
#et-boc .et-l h3,
#et-boc .et-l h4,
#et-boc .et-l h5,
#et-boc .et-l h6,
#et-boc .et-l hr,
#et-boc .et-l iframe,
#et-boc .et-l img,
#et-boc .et-l input,
#et-boc .et-l label,
#et-boc .et-l li,
#et-boc .et-l object,
#et-boc .et-l ol,
#et-boc .et-l p,
#et-boc .et-l span,
#et-boc .et-l strong,
#et-boc .et-l textarea,
#et-boc .et-l ul,
#et-boc .et-l video {
  text-align: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: 0 0;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: inherit;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: inherit;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="et-boc">
  <div class="et-l">
    <p>Foobar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the CSS there is the `#et-boc .et-l p` rule which should be hitting the paragraph tag but it's not.

I noticed that if I type it out as a separate CSS rule instead of grouping it with all of the others that it works. Does Chrome / Firefox put some sort of limit on how many selectors you can add into a single rule?

This is output automatically from the WordPress plugin Divi Builder if you are wondering.

Comment: this part is the culprit `not(.woocommerce-message, .star-rating)` ... there is a very low support for complex selector inside not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) on `:not`:

> The ability to list more than one selector is experimental and not yet widely supported.

It looks like only Safari 9+ supports it (no other browsers do). Once non-Safari browsers see that rule, they choke up.

Change the line:

```
#et-boc .et-l div:not(.woocommerce-message, .star-rating),
```

to two `:not`s instead:

```
#et-boc .et-l div:not(.woocommerce-message):not(.star-rating),
```

so that they only contain a simple selector.

```css
#et-boc .et-l .hentry,
#et-boc .et-l a,
#et-boc .et-l a:active,
#et-boc .et-l blockquote,
#et-boc .et-l div:not(.woocommerce-message):not(.star-rating),
#et-boc .et-l em,
#et-boc .et-l form,
#et-boc .et-l h1,
#et-boc .et-l h2,
#et-boc .et-l h3,
#et-boc .et-l h4,
#et-boc .et-l h5,
#et-boc .et-l h6,
#et-boc .et-l hr,
#et-boc .et-l iframe,
#et-boc .et-l img,
#et-boc .et-l input,
#et-boc .et-l label,
#et-boc .et-l li,
#et-boc .et-l object,
#et-boc .et-l ol,
#et-boc .et-l p,
#et-boc .et-l span,
#et-boc .et-l strong,
#et-boc .et-l textarea,
#et-boc .et-l ul,
#et-boc .et-l video {
  text-align: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: 0 0;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: inherit;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: inherit;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="et-boc">
  <div class="et-l">
    <p>Foobar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! I saw this as soon as I posted this question. Unfortunately this is output automatically from a WordPress plugin so it looks like they'll have to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: @TimothyFisher don't update the plugin or revert back to a previous version. Newer version aren't always good and you need to wait before using them

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can't do a list inside the `:not()`. You'll have to do two "not" lines.

CSS

```
#et-boc .et-l .hentry,
#et-boc .et-l a,
#et-boc .et-l a:active,
#et-boc .et-l blockquote,
#et-boc .et-l div:not(.woocommerce-message):not(.star-rating), // edit
#et-boc .et-l em,
#et-boc .et-l form,
#et-boc .et-l h1,
#et-boc .et-l h2,
#et-boc .et-l h3,
#et-boc .et-l h4,
#et-boc .et-l h5,
#et-boc .et-l h6,
#et-boc .et-l hr,
#et-boc .et-l iframe,
#et-boc .et-l img,
#et-boc .et-l input,
#et-boc .et-l label,
#et-boc .et-l li,
#et-boc .et-l object,
#et-boc .et-l ol,
#et-boc .et-l p,
#et-boc .et-l span,
#et-boc .et-l strong,
#et-boc .et-l textarea,
#et-boc .et-l ul,
#et-boc .et-l video {
  text-align: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: 0 0;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: inherit;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  text-shadow: inherit;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
```

Comment: they should be combined like shown in the other answer .. `not(A || B)` is equal to `not(A) && not(B)` and not to `not(A) || not(B)`